# What I need to know to do asp.net streaming

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication, video, streaming

I have an thing to create Internet shop to sell video views. And there are some rules, which I don't know how to do. The rules is:

> Loggined client can only view one video 3 times per day.
>   I read somewhere that I need to generate virtual links to video and server must hold it, for example, 3 hours OR until client looked up to the end the video, and then delete this virtual link and refresh player state to "start video position and waiting for start". Like on youtube but client shouldn't have a way to rewind the video.
>
> I need to hold situation that client who buy 'video01' give another client him page address or all attributes data from player tag. If second client don't buy 'video01' he shouldn't load it. (I think it's can be solved by cookies).
>
> After 180 video views, client's subscription must be stopped.

And finally question from me is how to play video from my website? Can anyone explain me how to make asp.net site with rules that I wrote the above? What technology I need to use?
I will be grateful if someone advise me a literature that I need to read to know how to do this? Perhaps for a start I need to know how to play video on asp.net webpages. 
What free flash player I should use for my solution, any examples please? Really need help.

P.S.: I need to use a free flash player to play videos, not silverlight.
The videos are on the remote servers, not on the local server where I hold the site.

Answer (score 1):

To limit the video as per your requirement you need to use [GenericHandlers](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx) in asp.net. It must be designed in such a way that the url must expire after reaching the above condition.

For Example, you can generate a random key that should append with the url (ie, QueryString) and store it in Database along with the time of generation. You can make the key expire after 3 hours then.

To play the video on your website you can add jQuery plugin [videojs](http://www.videojs.com/). The documentation will help you to add that simple HTML5+Flash video player.

Comment: Thanks. How I can delete key after the user finish the load video? I need to close videos stream when user get 100% loading or after 3 hours if he had extremly slow connection. And I need to disable scroling.

Comment: You don't need to delete the key. Instead you can check difference in time between the time of key generation and time of request. if its above 3 hours you can deny access. Also you can take the count of requests for the url. You must know how to use generic handlers in asp.net